# Token not refreshing silently: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ajax, azure

After about 30 minutes inactivity, any AJAX request throws the following exception and the user needs to reload the page in order to continue using the site.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/oaut…xxxxxxxx&x-client-SKU=ID_NET&x-client-ver=1.0.4.0.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:44300' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side is not allowing headers to all. check your server side if you have allowed access to all for get, post, put, update , etc method request. How's your backend?

Comment: No issue in server side as user can send request but it happens only after over 30 minutes inactivity.